# Git pull and Sync Buttons are disabled in Visual studio and we are using Azure repo

Tags: git, azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-repos

Git pull and Sync Buttons are disabled in Visual studio and we are using Azure repo.

I have taken Clone from Azure repo into visual studio and i did changes in code, Bymistake I deleted Add remote in source control manage remotes, So I have added again manage remote manually, now i want to take pull and push but pull and sync button are disabled, remote repositories are not available so how to resolve this problem

I want to connect azure repo to visal stuido and enable git pull and sync buttons in visual studio

Comment: My guess is if you re-clone, and then compare the remotes that are automatically created, with the ones you manually created, they will be different.

Comment: but I also have some changes the I need to push, before that we need to pull

Comment: If the repo isn't huge, you could clone a second copy and then compare the results of `git remote -vv` (or look at the remote settings in VS).

Comment: I have added a remote via manage remote (git menu) in visual studio but the remote repository not displaying and the pull and sync options are disabled. is there any setting missing please let me know

Comment: You can set the upstream tracking branch from the command line: `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/your-branch-name`. There is a (somewhat convoluted) work-around that would enable you to do it directly in VS as well, but the command line is much easier...