# Git pull and Sync Buttons are disabled in Visual studio and we are using Azure devops repo

Tags: git, azure, devops

Git pull and Sync Buttons are disabled in Visual studio and we are using Azure repo.

I have taken Clone from Azure repo into visual studio and i did changes in code, Bymistake I deleted Add remote in source control manage remotes in git menu in visual stuido, So I have added again manage remote manually, now i want to take pull and push but pull and sync button are disabled, remote repositories are not available so how to resolve this problem, is there any setting are missing for reconnect to remote (azure devops).please let me know

I want to connect azure repo to visal stuido and enable git pull and sync buttons in visual studio

I want to connect azure repo to visal stuido and enable git pull and sync buttons in visual studio

Comment: Are you the same person that asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76263165/184546)? Either way it's a dup.